# Should autoboxing be avoided in Java?

Tags: java, autoboxing

There are instances where a method expects a primitive type `double` and you pass a `Double` object as a parameter.

Since the compiler unboxes the passed object will this increase memory usage or decrease performance?

Answer (score 9):

This is what Java Notes says on [autoboxing](http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/basic_types/autoboxing.html):

> **Prefer primitive types**
>
> Use the primitive types where there is no need for objects for two
>   reasons.
>
> 1. Primitive types may be a lot faster than the corresponding wrapper
>      types, and are never slower.
> 2. The immutability (can't be changed after creation) of the wrapper
>      types may make their use impossible.
> 3. There can be some unexpected behavior involving == (compare
>      references) and .equals() (compare values). See the reference below
>      for examples.

Comment: Specific unexpected behavior includes NullPointerExceptions when unboxing.

Comment: autoboxing surprises: http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=27129

Comment: yep, but the question was about 'autoboxing'. If he would ask 'should I use primitives over the wrapper classes' then of course you are right, otherwise the autoboxing itself doesn't affect performance on the modern JVM's - at least from what I know.

Comment: @Kris: He asks if autoboxing should be avoided, which I answered with "Prefer Primitive Types". To his remark about "heaviness", I answered with my first bullet point.

Comment: @0A0D: true again, but you are still talking about heaviness of wrapper classes vs. primitives and not about heaviness of autoboxing itself :)

Comment: "For two reasons" - lists 3 haha :-)

Answer (score 7):

The rule of thumb is: always use primitives if possible.

There are cases where this is not possible, like collections, so use wrappers only then.

Answer (score 5):

It's a design-choice and not trivially answered for every case.

There are several items that *could* influence your decision:

Advantages:

- Auto-boxing and auto-unboxing *can* make your code *easier* to read:

  Leaving out all the unnecessary `.doubleValue()` and `Double.valueOf()` reduces the visual noise and can make your code easier to read.
- Auto-boxing allows you to easily use collections of primitive values (such as a `List<Double>`, ...)

Disadvantages:

- excessive, unnecessary auto-boxing and auto-unboxing *can* hinder your performance.

  For example, if you have an API that *returns* a `double` and another API that *expects* a `double`, but you handle the value as a *Double* in between, then you're doing useless auto-boxing.
- auto-unboxing can introduce a `NullPointerException` where you don't expect it:

  ```
  public void frobnicate(Double d) {
    double result = d / 2;
    // ...
  }
  ```
- using collections of auto-boxed values uses *a lot* more memory than a comparable `double[]` for example.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to avoid autoboxing if talking about performance, JVM should handle that. The only thing you should consider is a readability of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Autoboxing should be avoided. It can lead to errors because of overloading and it has some  performance impact.
Nonetheless it may not be an issue in your application. But be aware of the impact.

Comment: the link is not valid anymore.