# Unnecessary unboxing and unboxing performance in Java

Tags: java, performance, compiler-warnings, autoboxing

For a code excerpt like the following

```
  int a;
  Integer b = new Integer(1);
  a = b.intValue();
```

the `Java` compiler generates an "Unnecessary unboxing" warning.

Is that superfluous, or is there more substance behind it? Other answers (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915823/which-is-better-in-terms-of-performance-implicit-auto-unboxing-or-explicit-un) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610664/should-autoboxing-be-avoided-in-java)) seem to hinder towards auto-boxing and auto-unboxing being expensive when used extensively, but of negligible to zero impact when done a few times only.

Comment: The unboxing is not the performance eater. As far as I understand it, the boxing part is the performance eater since every autoboxing creates a new `Integer` object (aside from mabye cached values).

Comment: And besides, `new Integer(1)` is not auto-boxing.  It is manual boxing ... done the wrong way.  (It should be `Integer.valueOf(1)` or simply `b = 1`.)

Comment: [What does your profiler tell you?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890222/analyzing-code-for-efficiency)

Comment: An answer like "it is just an overreaction by the JDK" would be adequate, if that were the case.